# Outgoing network bandwidth is high even for empty response

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nginx, performance

I have a simple nginx server that monitors the requests and store them in the access logs. The requests contain data in query parameters and are about 500 bytes. My output is just a HTTP 204 response. But, when I monitor the network bandwidth, I am seeing the incoming rate as 8.44 Mbit/s and outgoing rate as 5.19 MBit/s.

Question is, why is the outgoing rate high?

The output from "tcpflow -p -C -i eth0 port 80" is below.

```
GET ############## HTTP/1.1
Host: ##############
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Forwarded: for="[############]"
Origin: ###########
Referer: #########
Save-Data: on
Scheme: http
Via: 1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy
X-Forwarded-For: #################
Connection: Keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-J710FN Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36


write error to stdout

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2017 04:54:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: How are you doing this monitoring?

Comment: I used "nload" to check the status.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because without knowing how many requests the server receives and what other traffic is on the interface there is no way to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

> why is the outgoing rate high?

I don't think we can reasonably answer that question but we can give you some ideas on how to answer it yourself.

You appear to be focusing on the traffic generated by your http server. Lots of other processes on a system can use the network.

I would be tempted to use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) to get a detailed view of the packets on the line. From that I can learn what other traffic besides HTTP is active and how it contributes to the overall network usage. I can then analyse further as required.

Comment: That's what I'd do, too, but if ssh'ed in it becomes important to exempt your monitoring system from the monitoring, otherwise all you see is the outgoing packets to you, trying to tell you about all the outgoing packets, most of which are to you.  `tcpdump -n -n -i eth0 not host 192.168.3.4` works for me (assuming I'm ssh'ed in from 192.168.3.4).

Comment: Absolutely, that's a valuable learning experience too. I'm guessing that the OP is using ssh to get to the box which will likely be contributing to usage too.

Answer (score 0):

If your incoming requests are larger in volume than your outgoing responses, then your profile is somewhat unusual for a web service - most web services send back far more than they receive.

Looking at the output you give, nginx's response is about 167 bytes, and you say the average request is about 500 bytes.

So if we do a very quick back of the napkin calculation, you have about 1MB (8Mb) incoming per second @500 byte per request: `1000000/500 = 2000 requests/sec`. I suspect not all requests are returning the 170 byte responses you shared, because `6000000/8/170 = 4411` - or, in other words, either some responses are substantially larger than 170 bytes, or (less likely) your server is responding twice to each request.

So I guess the question is whether that rough range (2000 to ~4000) of requests/responses per second is expected.

Comment: Your calculations only cover the HTTP layer payload. If you take into account the overhead at TCP, IP, and link layers you should find much less difference between the number of bytes sent and received.